# Очень медленный процесс сканирования открытых портов

Tags: c#

```
// работа на тему Информационная безопасность
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string IP = "";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "PortScanner";
            UserInput();
            PortScan();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void UserInput()
        {
            Console.Write("IP Address:", ConsoleColor.White);
            IP = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void PortScan()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            TcpClient Scan = new TcpClient();
            foreach (int s in Ports)
            {
                try
                {
                    Scan.Connect(IP, s);
                    Console.WriteLine($"[{s}] | OPEN", ConsoleColor.Green);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"[{s}] | CLOSED", ConsoleColor.Red);
                }
            }
        }

        private static int[] Ports = new int[]
        {
        1,
        2,
        3,
        80,
        };

    }
}
```

Очень долго и длительно сканирует порты на указаном IP. Как ускорить процесс?

Как указать порты одной строкой? (глупо выходит их вот так вводить через запятую)

Comment: Долго - это сколько? Порты одной строкой `int[] ports = "1 2 3 80".Split(' ').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();`. Тот еще изврат, но вы просили - получите :)

Comment: Я чего-то не понимаю, или, чтобы указать порты одной строкой, достаточно написать их в одну строку? Ну вот же: ```private static int[] Ports = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 80,};```, нет?

Comment: Переходите на асинхронщину. Каждая проверка - это пустое ожидание таймаута сетевого соединения в случае если порт закрыт, поэтому это время простоя можно совершенно спокойно использовать для запуска другой задачи.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Если очень просто**, то ответ такой: Используйте асинхронность, не ждите выполнение другой проверки!
В вашем коде надо сделать пару вещей:

1. `Main` сделать с `void` на `async Task`.
2. Сделает задачу (`Task`), которая будет проверять один порт.

   - То есть, у `PortScan` выкидываем все лишнее (цикл, очистку консоли)
   - Аргументом требуем порт
   - Меняем с `void` на `async Task`.
   - Переделываем `.Connect()` на `.ConnectAsync()`, добавив в начало `await`.
   - Сам `TcpClient` оборачиваем в `using`, ибо его надо закрывать!
3. Преобразуем массив ваших портов в задачи, которые потом запускаем через `Task.WhenAll()`.

В итоге получиться нечто такое:

```
private static string IP = "";

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Title = "PortScanner";
    UserInput();
    Console.Clear();

    var tasks = Ports.Select(x => PortScan(x));
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void UserInput()
{
    Console.Write("IP Address:", ConsoleColor.White);
    IP = Console.ReadLine();
}

private static async Task PortScan(int port)
{
    using TcpClient Scan = new TcpClient();

    try
    {
        await Scan.ConnectAsync(IP, port);
        Console.WriteLine($"[{port}] | OPEN", ConsoleColor.Green);
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[{port}] | CLOSED", ConsoleColor.Red);
    }
}

private static int[] Ports = new int[]
{
1,
2,
3,
80,
};
```

Теперь у вас проверка портов пойдет асинхронно, то есть без ожидания завершения предыдущей проверки.

Но, у вас есть ряд моментов, которые **можно улучшить**, давайте сделаем это:

1. **`UserInput()`** - Почему этот метод не отдает результат, а записывает в некую статичную переменную? Ведь его задача, это спросить пользователя и отдать нам для работы его ответ. Давайте напишем чуть по-другому:

   ```
   static string AskUser(string message)
   {
       Write($"{message}: ");
       return ReadLine();
   }
   ```

   Теперь метод отдает нам то, что ввел пользователь.
2. **Вывод цветного сообщения** - тут стоит тоже сделать удобный метод, например такой:

   ```
   static void ColoredText(string title, string text, ConsoleColor color)
   {
       Write($"{title}: ");
       ForegroundColor = color;
       WriteLine(text);
       ResetColor();
   }
   ```

   Теперь можно удобно вывести текст, допустим, статуса порта.
3. **IP** - Научитесь использовать правильные типы, а не некие базовые. Для ip в c# есть специальный класс `IPAddress`, работайте с ним! Давайте сделаем метод, который будет спрашивать пользователя ip, если он некорректен, то просит по новой, а в случае успешного ввода, отдаст нам `IPAddress`:

   ```
   static IPAddress AskIp(string message)
   {
       while (true)
       {
           var reply = AskUser(message);
           if (IPAddress.TryParse(reply, out var ip))
           {
               return ip;
           }
           else
           {
               ColoredText(reply, "Не является IP", ConsoleColor.Red);
               ReadKey();
               Clear();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. **Улучшим метод сканирования** - сейчас задача ждет таймаута, это тоже можно изменить:

   - Сделаем отдельный метод, (некую обертку над клиентом, которую по-хорошему лучше засунуть в отдельный класс), который будет пытаться сделать соединение, но также асинхронно будет запущен некий таймер, который выдаст ошибку, если выполниться он быстрее:

     ```
     static async Task TimeoutConnectAsync(IPAddress ip, int port, TimeSpan connectTimeout = default)
     {
         if (connectTimeout == default) 
             connectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);

         using var client = new TcpClient();

         var cancelTask = Task.Delay(connectTimeout);
         var connectTask = client.ConnectAsync(ip, port);

         await Task.WhenAny(connectTask, cancelTask);

         if (cancelTask.IsCompleted)
         {
             throw new TimeoutException();
         }
     }
     ```
   - Ну и сама задача проверки одного порта:

     ```
     static async Task CheckPortAsync(IPAddress ip, int port, TimeSpan connectTimeout = default)
     {
         bool result;

         try
         {
             await TimeoutConnectAsync(ip, port, connectTimeout);
             result = true;
         }
         catch
         {
             result = false;
         }

         ColoredText($"{ip}:{port}", result ? "Открыт" : "Закрыт", result ? ConsoleColor.Green : ConsoleColor.Red);
     }
     ```

   Теперь при проверке порта, если он не доступен в течении 500ms, мы считаем его "закрытым".
5. **Множественная проверка** - вам не нужно инициализировать новый массив с портами, достаточно воспользоваться `params` и передавать в метод все порты через запятую. Давайте сделаем новый метод, который будет принимать список портов, ну и проверит их все разом:

   ```
   static async Task CheckPortsAsync(IPAddress ip, params int[] ports)
   {
       var tasks = ports.Select(x => CheckPortAsync(ip, x));
       await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
   }
   ```

   Вызывается это просто, `await CheckPortsAsync(ip, 1, 2, 3, 80);`

Я тут не стал говорить про ООП и прочие особенности, просто знайте, что в одном классе это писать не хорошо, разбейте все это по разным классам, которые будут отвечать за что-то одно.

**Весь код:**

```
static async Task Main()
{
    var ip = AskIp("IP Address");
    await CheckPortsAsync(ip, 1, 2, 3, 80);
}

static async Task CheckPortAsync(IPAddress ip, int port, TimeSpan connectTimeout = default)
{
    bool result;

    try
    {
        await TimeoutConnectAsync(ip, port, connectTimeout);
        result = true;
    }
    catch
    {
        result = false;
    }

    ColoredText($"{ip}:{port}", result ? "Открыт" : "Закрыт", result ? ConsoleColor.Green : ConsoleColor.Red);
}

static async Task CheckPortsAsync(IPAddress ip, params int[] ports)
{
    var tasks = ports.Select(x => CheckPortAsync(ip, x));
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

static async Task TimeoutConnectAsync(IPAddress ip, int port, TimeSpan connectTimeout = default)
{
    if (connectTimeout == default)
        connectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);

    using var client = new TcpClient();

    var cancelTask = Task.Delay(connectTimeout);
    var connectTask = client.ConnectAsync(ip, port);

    await Task.WhenAny(connectTask, cancelTask);

    if (cancelTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        throw new TimeoutException();
    }
}

static void ColoredText(string title, string text, ConsoleColor color)
{
    Write($"{title}: ");
    ForegroundColor = color;
    WriteLine(text);
    ResetColor();
}

static string AskUser(string message)
{
    Write($"{message}: ");
    return ReadLine();
}
static IPAddress AskIp(string message)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var reply = AskUser(message);
        if (IPAddress.TryParse(reply, out var ip))
        {
            return ip;
        }
        else
        {
            ColoredText(reply, "Не является IP", ConsoleColor.Red);
            ReadKey();
            Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

**Результат выполнения:**

[image: Result]

Вот, собственно, и все, направление я вам показал, остальное за вами!

- P.S. Почему `ReadLine()`, а не `Console.ReadLine()`? Потому что мне так удобней) Делается при помощи `using static System.Console;`.
- P.S.S. Так, как здесь идет асинхронность, то выводить результат может "коряво", тут уже играйтесь с `lock` и прочими приблудами. Ну а вообще, по-хорошему, лучше делать `Task<bool>` и уже после того, как все задачи завершились, выводить результат. Метод проверки не обязан выводить что либо, это, по сути, нарушение SOLID, так что подумайте об этом!

---

> можно что-то оригинальное придумать, типа 1-80, 123, 443, 500-2000

Если нужно такое, то можно написать примерно следующий метод:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> ParseRange(string range) => 
    range.Split(',')
    .Select(x => x.Split('-'))
    .Select(x => (First: int.Parse(x.First()), Last: int.Parse(x.Last())))
    .SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range(x.First, x.Last - x.First + 1))
    .OrderBy(x => x);
```

Тут, по сути, все просто:

1. Разбиваем все по запятой, что в итоге выдаст нам коллекцию строк.
2. Каждое значение в этой коллекции разбиваем по `-`, что даст нам, по сути, коллекцию, состоящую из коллекций строк.
3. Теперь нам нужен некий объект, который будет содержать первое и последнее значение каждой коллекции. Если там всего одно значение, то мин и макс будут одинаковыми. `(First: 1, Last: 2)` - это кортеж (можно взять и анонимный тип (`new {First: 1, Last: 2}`).
4. Осталось нам сгенерировать цифры, для этого есть `Enumerable.Range()`, который даст числа в указанном диапазоне.
5. Все, полученный результат сортируем.

Вызываем:

```
var ports = ParseRange("1, 5-10, 13, 80, 100-100, 115-120")
```

Результат:

```
1
5
6
7
8
9
10
13
80
100
115
116
117
118
119
120
```

Comment: `Как указать порты одной строкой?` я бы еще ввод диапазона сканипрования прикрутил. Насколько я понял, автор именно про это спросил, но странным образом. Я просто пошутил у него в комментах.можно что-то оригинальное придумать, типа `1-80, 123, 443, 500-2000`. Еще увидел 2 опечатки, в тексте в самом начале, и в коде двойной `await`.

Comment: @aepot Дополнил, опечатки (дурацкий копипаст) вроде убрал. Спасибо.

Comment: Шикарный Linq, да и ответ в целом. (плюсик уже стоит) :)

Comment: Спасибо большое вам, теперь понял.

Comment: Правда на 52ой строке ошибка почему-то "Имя "client" не существует в текущем контексте." - что делать? вроде же все правильно.

Comment: @Zekoy Внимательно смотрите код. `using var client = new TcpClient();`

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/7i5BeJL.png

Comment: Если убрать `using` то код начнет выполнятся но после найденого порта закроется, с скобками тоже ошибка(

Comment: @Zekoy Значит у вас старая версия языка, используйте старый формат, что-то по типу `using(var client = new TcpClient()){ //код }`.

Comment: Я в настройках проекта поставил самую последнию версию языка и добавил эту строку но все равно говорит что не существует в этом контексте. https://i.imgur.com/s3uXfTz.png

Comment: Я убрал скобки и ошибки нету но при запуске почему-то сканирует лишь один порт и закрывается.

Comment: @Zekoy Вы не знаете как должны размещаться объекты в коде или что? Я вам дал что? `using(var client = new TcpClient()){ //код }`, где `//код` - это все, что использует этот `client`. Вы берете и пишете за пределами этого блока и спрашиваете "Хм, что-то не находит". По поводу "сканирует лишь один порт" - мне это не говорит вообще не о чем. Я вам дам полностью рабочий код, даже дал анимацию того, как это выполняется. А вот как у вас это сейчас, я без понятия. Смотрите внимательней еще раз то, что вы там накопировали (лучше напишите сами, обдумывая каждую строку), сверяйте с тем, что у меня.

Comment: @Zekoy Вот вам [онлайн](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uBL8xy). То, что закомментировано, это сделано в связи с особенностями сайта, ибо цвет он не выводит (иероглифы), а также что-то спрашивать не захотел ip (вписал статично).